# In CRM 2011, best way to send information from javascript to plugins

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I have an HTML web resource on a CRM 2011 form that users will be entering data into.  This data will be required by CRM create/update plugins if the user chooses to save the main form, but there is no functional requirement that the data needs to be saved to any field on the entity.  I am considering a hidden dummy field that the data could be saved to, but am wondering if there is anything more elegant for persisting data from the client to server technologies.  I've done some research on "sharedvariables" but haven't been able to determine if they might meet this need.  Any example of setting a value using JavaScript and then retrieving it from a plugin would be valuable.

Edit:  I just wanted to clarify the response that I received based on my testing.  While CRM has "SharedVariables" available for both plugin and scripting use, any data saved in scripts will not be available to plugins.  Data saved by one javascript function to "SharedVariables" will be available to other javascript functions registered for the same event, and data saved by a plugin is available to other plugins registered for the same event, but the data is not persisted from script to plugins or vise-versa.  This leaves dummy fields as the only option for persisting data from javascript to plugins.  As NickNow suggested, unless you need to persist the data to a database, deleting it on a pre-plugin would be a good idea.  Thanks Nicknow!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hidden/dummy field is the correct approach. `SharedVariables` don't exist, from the standpoint of a plugin, until the data is sent to the server.

The form save is just a UI to trigger the Create or Update event - from the platform's standpoint you are just sending an entity logical name, the record guid (for an update), and the fields/values. The plugin has no knowledge, and shouldn't require knowledge, of how the event was triggered.

What I do is create a field (such as `new_internalmessaging') as a text field (since I'll never persist the value to the database I just make it a 2000 character string). During a JavaScript OnSave event I grab whatever data I need into an object and create a JSON string which I then use to populate the field.

In my Pre-Create and Pre-Update plugins I retrieve the string and deserialize it to an object for use in my plugin (I can also place it into a `SharedVariable` at this point if I need it for a post plugin). At this point the plugin code should remove `new_internalmessaging` from the `Target`.

I do this to ensure the data in that field will never get persisted to CRM.

Comment: what will be the better approach 1- On Pre-Create/Pre-Update retrieve the string and based on that string perform your custom logic 2- Store the string in SharedVariable, and then On Post-Create/Post-Update, get the string from SharedVariable and perform your custom logic ?

Comment: That is going to depend on whether your logic should execute Pre or Post. I can't really tell you how to design without knowing the business requirements. Both methods are viable and I've used both in projects before.